# How to select array components from database of joomla 2.5

Tags: php, database, joomla

I have a problem with joomla, when I retrieve multi columns from database content of joomla 2.5, where the columns are "id","introtext","id". I got the output as follow

```
Array([0] => Array([id]=>1 [introtext]=> lorent ipsum [catid]=> 8) [1] => Array([id]=>2 [introtext]=> lorent ipsum [catid]=>9))
```

I want to get id's, introtext's, catid's separately with php. Please help me... Thank you

Comment: I have tried a php script as follow <?php   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->select(array('id','introtext','catid'));
  $query->from('#__content');
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadAssocList();
  print_r(extract($results));
?> Now, I want to get 'id', 'introtext', 'catid'. I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $d){
  echo "id: ".$d['id'];
  echo "introtext: ".$d['introtext'];
  echo "catid: ".$d['catid'];
}
```